# Understanding json response types in Python, and IDE autocomplete

Tags: python, json, dictionary, python-requests, pycharm

I'm coming from a Java background and thought I'd try some Python today, so perhaps you can keep that in mind when explaining :)

I do the following:

```
resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
something = jsonpickle.unpickler.decode(resp.text)
```

Server responds fine (with Json content). I (think I) understand that `something` is a `dict` because `type(something)` gives me `<class 'dict'>`.

The documentation for the `decode` method though says the return type is `Any`.

1. What's happening there?

Also, [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) document lists a couple of methods for `dict` like `dict.clear()` which PyCharm does not offer me on my `something` dict.

2. Why is that?

Comment: I can't answer the part about PyCharm but decoding JSON gives you the equivalent structure in Python. If the outermost JSON is an object `{....}` you will get a dict; if the outermost JSON is an array `[....]` you will get a list; etc.

Comment: Python is *dynamically typed*; as PyCharm can't see the string you're decoding, how's it supposed to know what methods the result will have? As the docs you've read have already told you, that method could return `Any`thing!

Comment: You may be able to use the `.json()` function (which returns a Python dictionary) of the response object to decode your json. Example: `resp.json()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It decodes whatever it is given to a python object (in this case it is a dict),but it could be a list, or an int or a float or a string or a handful of other basic types. you could also get the json back with `resp.json()`(probably im not sure what jsonpickle is it may be more than just json) ....
2. you must tell pycharm it is a dict otherwise pycharm has no way of knowing what that method will return. for pycharm to know you can do this with

   ```
   assert isinstance(something,dict)
   ```

Comment: Awesome, that let's me use the dict. Can I assume this is the Python equivalent to casting like '(dict) something ' would work in Java?

Comment: not really its an assertion if it is anything else(string,list,int,etc) it will raise an error that will crash the program unless you catch it (ie if the request returns something other than what you expect).. but pycharm can then use that to say "this thing is a dict, so ill show you autocomplete stuff for dict")

Comment: Understand, it was a dict before the assertion. Thanks!